# tkinter GUI crashes as button clicked because of heavy code while using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

[This is the issue image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMTGX.jpg) hi i have a code of python tkinter. in which i am using selenium when i click button gui crashes.
anyone who know the issue. below is the code. this code use selenium to login in linkedin.
whenever i clicked on the login button it crashes but selenium is and code working fine. also working good on cmd. but in gui it crashes.

```py
def login_verify():
    global username1
    global pasword1

    username1 = username_verify.get()
    pasword1 = password_verify.get()
    if len(username1) < 10 or len(pasword1) < 4:
        print("if state")
        Label(main_screen, text = "please enter the password and email").pack()
    else:
        print("entered")
        Label(main_screen, text = "Wait verifying the password and mail!").pack()
        print(username1)
        print(pasword1)
        login_check()

        if pas == True and ml == True:
            driver.quit()
            main_screen.destroy()
        else:
            driver.quit()
            Label(main_screen, text = "wrong mail or password:").pack()

#GUI code 

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    global username_verify
    global password_verify
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    
    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()
    
    Label(main_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(main_screen, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(main_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(main_screen, text="Password *").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(main_screen, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(main_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(main_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command = lambda: login_verify()).pack()
    main_screen.mainloop()
 
def login_check():
    global pas
    global ml
    global driver    
  
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #-------------------login-------------------------------------------------
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin")
    emaile = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    emaile.send_keys(username1)
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    password.send_keys(pasword1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("error-for-password")
        pas = False
        print("password error")
        driver.quit()
    except:
        pas = True
        print("pas ok")
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("error-for-username")
        ml = False
        driver.quit()
        print("user error")  
    except:
        print("user ok")
        ml = True       
 main_account_screen()
```

Comment: How do you define "crashes"? Does your program literally quit, or does it just freeze while the selenium code is running?

Comment: tkinter shows not responding after click

Comment: Can you share the log ? it might help